# Approximation property and separability

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I have a question regarding separability. Let $Y$ be a normed space, and suppose the identity $I$ is the pointwise limit of finite range operators $F_n$.

> Does this imply that $Y$ is separable?

*Context*: giving conditions under which the approximation property holds

*My thoughts*: this is true, I think. Indeed, $F_n(Y)$ is finite dimensional hence separable (being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. Pick therefore a countable dense subset $C_n$, and define $C:=\bigcup_n C_n$, which I claim to be dense.

Let $y\in Y$. We know $y=\lim_n F_n(y)$ and $F_n(y)=\lim_j c_j^n$, for $c_j^n \in C_n$. But then $||y-c_j^n||\leq ||y-F_n(y)||+||F_n(y)-c^n_j||$. The first term is small for $n$ large, and fixing $n$, I can surely find $j=j(n)$ such that the second is as small as the first one. So I found $y=\lim_n c_{j(n)}^n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. If $E_n$ is a basis for $\mathrm{im}F_n$, then $Y=\overline{\sum_n\mathrm{Span}(E_n)}=\overline{\mathrm{Span}(\bigcup_nE_n)}$; since $\bigcup_nE_n$ is countable, $Y$ is separable.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. I'd write:

If $y \in Y$ let $\varepsilon >0$ be given. Then we know that $F_n(y) \to I(y)=y$ as $n \to \infty$ so we find $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $\| F_n(y) - y\| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then as $C_N$ is dense in $F_N[Y]$, we have $c \in C_N \subseteq C$ such that $\|F_n(y) - c\| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. It follows that $\|y - c\| < \varepsilon$ and we're done.